# problem with image upload from aws lambda to s3 bucket through nest js

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, nestjs

I am trying to build a REST API using API Gateway and Lambda. I need the client to upload an image in a form along with other fields through API Gateway to Lambda. I'm using Lambda Function Proxy Integrations.I'm using nest js and convert it to lambda.It works fine on localhost but when I try from lambda it receives data for other fields correctly. But the image is corrupted and its size almost doubles.

Here is my nest js code:

The controller post request is

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('image'))

async addNews(@Body() NewsDataDTO:NewsDataDTO,@UploadedFiles() file){  

if(file[0]){
   NewsDataDTO.image =  await 
   this.imageUploadService.fileupload(file[0].
   buffer,uuid()+file[0].originalname,file[0].mimetype);

   const image=sharp(file[0].buffer);

   let newImage= await image.resize(200,200).toBuffer();

   NewsDataDTO.thumbnailImage =  await 
   this.imageUploadService.fileupload(newImage,uuid()+file[0].
   originalname,file[0].mimetype);
}
```

and the imageUploadService code is here:

```
async fileupload(file: Buffer, urlKey: string, mimetype: any) {

const params = {
  Body: file,
  Bucket: 'bucketName',
  Key: urlKey,
  ContentType: mimetype,

};

const image=await s3
.putObject(params)
.promise();

return `https://bucketUrl/${urlKey}`
```